# Como faço para chamar uma .dll e declarar funções em C++.Net

Tags: c++, dll

Estou migrando um projeto para C++, porém estou com dificuldades em chamar a .dll

Este é código:

```
int  LoadDLL (void) {
   char handle;

   //! Carrega a dll ...
   handle = LoadLibrary(L"c:\windows\system\minhadll.dll");

   //! Verifica se a dll foi corretamente carregada..
   if (handle) {

   }
   return handle; 
}
```

O erro se encontra no "=" do handle:

> "  IntelliSense: um valor do tipo "HMODULE" não pode ser atribuído para uma entidade do tipo "int""

O que estou fazendo de errado, e o que recomendam ?

Comment: Qual é o problema que está tendo com o código atual? PS: nao precisa (nem deve) declarar o handle 2x como char.

Comment: Estou com erro no LoadLibrary, :Erro: HMODULE

Comment: Faça o seguinte, dê uma editada na pergunta e ponha todos os detalhes relevantes, para que alguém possa ajudar. Dê uma lida na página linkada aqui para algumas dicas legais: **[ask]**

Comment: Certo, vou seguir dica... 
Obrigado...

Comment: o HMODULE provavelmente é o seguinte: nesse caso, teria que ser `HMODULE handle;` no lugar do `char handle;`. E só declare uma vez.

Comment: Certo, vou verificar aqui!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelos comentários, acredito que o problema esteja na declaração do handle:

```
HMODULE LoadDLL(void) {
   HMODULE handle;

   // Carrega a dll ...
   handle = LoadLibrary(L"c:\windows\system\minhadll.dll");

   // Verifica se a dll foi corretamente carregada..
   if (handle == NULL) {
      //Indicar que deu erro
   }
   return handle; 
}
```

Notar que eu mudei o código da verificação para o caso de erro, veja se é o que vc quer.

Comment: Isso, eu fiz essa alteração, mas no caso o return handle, tive que definir como char(handle), ai funcionou!

Comment: Use `HMODULE LoadDLL(void)` no lugar de `int LoadDLL (void)`, pra nao precisar desse _cast_.

Comment: Também deu certo!!!

Comment: Muito obrigado, Bacco!